# Are there any Gaussian like or Dirichlet distributions for integers?

Tags: probability

I am curious if I can generate integers from Gaussian (or Dirichlet) distribution. I could not find any such idea in Google.. If there no Gaussian for integers, then why?

Thanks

Comment: (1) If you have a distribution $f$ of real numbers, you can define a distribution $g$ on the integers by letting $\displaystyle g(n) = {f(n) \over S}$, where $\displaystyle S=\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} f(n)$. (2) You could also use the Gaussian distribution to generate a random real number, then round that real number to the closest integer.

Comment: You'll have to specify what properties of the Gaussian you want to retain, precisely -- what would make a discrete distribution "Gaussian-like" to you?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Dirichlet Multinomial, $DirMult(n, \vec{\alpha})$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet-multinomial_distribution